# How would spin of a binary depend on its mass?

Tags: angular-momentum, astrophysics, dimensional-analysis, precession, binary-stars

I have been reading an article about a code that uses precession analysis on spin of binaries. At the beginning of the article authors describe units of code where they take $c=1$ (speed of light) and $G=1$ (universal gravitational constant). They also take the total mass of the binary to be $M=m1+m2=1$. The relation between the values are given as following(note that  $L$ in code really is--> $c*L/(G*M^2)$):
$$q=\frac{m_2}{m_1}<1$$
$$m_{1}=\frac{M}{1+q}$$
$$m_2=\frac{qM}{(1+q)}$$
$$S_1=\chi_{1}m_{1}^2$$
$$S_2=\chi_{2}m_{2}^2$$
My question is why the spin depends on the mass squared?

Comment: Kerr black holes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In units where $c=G=1$, the unit of spin and angular momentum is mass squared. To get a dimensionless measure of spin you need to divide by something with dimensions of mass squared. The most logical to thing to take is the mass of the body squared. Consequently, the dimensionless measure of spin $\chi$ is simply defined by the relation

$$\chi_i \equiv \frac{S_i}{m_i^2}$$

This is convention mostly. In the paper you were reading, it clearly needed to be clarified that this definition of $\chi$ was being used. Otherwise the reader might be left with the impression that the spin was being "adimensionalized" by the total mass $M$.